Laravel 11 Passport token Error handling - OAuthServerException
i am trying to make a json error response when the request doesn't have a valid token in it.
as a default laravel redirects to the login route.
My bootstrap/app.php is as given below
bootstrap/app.php
<?php

use Illuminate\Foundation\Application;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Configuration\Exceptions;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Configuration\Middleware;
use Laravel\Passport\Exceptions\OAuthServerException;


return Application::configure(basePath: dirname(__DIR__))
    ->withRouting(
        web: __DIR__.'/../routes/web.php',
        api: __DIR__.'/../routes/api.php',
        commands: __DIR__.'/../routes/console.php',
        health: '/up',
    )
    ->withMiddleware(function (Middleware $middleware) {
        $middleware->alias([
            //
        ]);
    })
    ->withExceptions(function (Exceptions $exceptions) {
        $exceptions->render(function (Throwable $e, Request $request) {
            if ($e instanceof OAuthServerException) {
                return response()->json([
                    'error' => $e->getErrorType(),
                    'message' => $e->getMessage(),
                    'hint' => $e->getHint(),
                ], $e->getHttpStatusCode());
            }
        });
    })->create();

the response is just 500 internal server error with no body
how can i do this properly ?

no body on response, but should have a trace to a method/line right?

WARN  thrown in C:\xampp82\htdocs\villagezone\bootstrap\app.php on line 22.
WARN  PHP Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: {closure}(): Argument #2 ($request) must be of type Request, Illuminate\Http\Request given, called in C:\xampp82\htdocs\villagezone\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler.php on line 675 and defined in C:\xampp82\htdocs\villagezone\bootstrap\app.php:22.
line 22 is
$exceptions->render(function (Throwable $e, Request $request) {

OAuthServerException isn't Laravel or Symfony exception. try with shouldRenderJsonWhen
